# Copy files from the latest sub directory in c#

Tags: c#

I have been struggling with this for a few days now and cannot figure it out.

I need to copy files from the last created sub directory in a directory, the sub directory has a few sub directories as well to navigate before I get to the files and that is where the problem comes in.

I hope I made this clear, I will give an example of the directories below, thanks in advance for the help.

```
C:\ProgramFiles\BuildOutput\mmh\LongTerm\**49**\release\MarketMessageHandler\Service\
```

The number highlighted in bold is the sub directory that I need to find the latest one and in the services folder is where I need to copy the files from...

Here is my code I tried

string sourceDir = @"\sttbedbsd001\BuildOutput\mmh\LongTerm\51\release\MarketMessageHandler\Service";
                string target = @"C:\Users\gwessels\Desktop\test\";

```
            string[] sDirFiles = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

            string targetDir;

            if (sDirFiles.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (string file in sDirFiles)
                {
                    string[] splitFile = file.Split('\\');
                    string copyFile = Path.GetFileName(file);
                    string source = sourceDir + "\\" + copyFile;

                    targetDir = target + copyFile;

                    try
                    {
                        if (File.Exists(targetDir))
                        {
                            File.Delete(targetDir);
                            File.Copy(source, targetDir);
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            File.Copy(source, targetDir);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Define "latest one" - do you mean the highest number? Or the latest create date?

Comment: What is the root directory that you use? Is it a static directory that you have stored somewhere or how do you determine it?

Comment: The directory is stored on a local server, with latest one I meant everytime there is a new build a new folder will be created with all the same sub directories 49 50 51 etc

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `LongTerm` directory is known since it is stored somewhere(f.e.  Application-Settings):

```
string longTermDirectory = Properties.Settings.Default.LongTermDirectory;
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(longTermDirectory);
dir.Create(); // does nothing if it already exists
int Number = int.MinValue;
DirectoryInfo latestFolder = dir.EnumerateDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(d => int.TryParse(d.Name, out Number))
    .Select(Directory => new { Directory, Number })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Number)
    .Select(x => x.Directory)
    .First();
```

`Directory.EnumerateDirectories` with `SearchOption.AllDirectories` enumerates all directories recursively. `Enumerable.OrderByDescending` with the number of the directory-name will order them numerically and highest first(so 50 before 49 and 100 before 99).